# Is it necessary to create a user named 'git' to setup a git server?

Tags: linux, git, git-server

`git@domain` already exists in my university network.

However, the Ubuntu 18.04 server that host `git@domain` is very unstable.

So I wished to set up a Debian server and install with Git.

Can I use hostname other than `git` to setup Git server?

It is necessary to create `git` user account for Git server to work?

Because I read many guides[[1]](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)[[2]](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server)[[3]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps), all of them ask to run `adduser git` command.

Comment: It's not necessary but it is recommended for security reasons. If you run a git server on the machine (that accepts remote connections) then you must run it as some username and you are giving remote access out to anything on your system that can be accessed by that username

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended to create a dedicated account (for security reason as commented)

However, nothing in Git involves a specific user name.

And git@aserver can be seen as an SSH URL, which means there would not even be a "Git server", but simply an [sshd (SSH daemon)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) listening for queries in order to access repositories owned by that account( be it named '`git`' or any other name)